# Load more in visual composer wordpress

Tags: visual-composer

I'm using visual composer on my wordpress site.

Is it possible to have load more posts on button click in Visual Composer? Do I need to use a plugin to do this? Does anybody know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible.

With Visual Composer, u can add the element **"Post Grid"**, this have the option **"Display Style"** and u can select **"load more button"**. [More here](https://vc.wpbakery.com/video-academy/post-and-custom-posts-type-grid/)

***NOTE:*** It only shows the hidden post, it does **not actually load it**, it was only hidden.